# How to find the reference of a List in Scala

Tags: list, scala, collections, reference, memory-address

I have a List(fruits) that I want to find and print the reference(memory address) of it, How can I?

```scala
val fruits:List[String]=List("apple","orange","pear")
```

Comment: WDYM with the _"references"_ of it?

Comment: The reference of the fruits Object @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Still, I don't understand, WDYM with the references of the fruits objects? Do you mean their memory addresses?

Comment: Yes, I mean the memory address of fruit or any other collection.

Comment: Well, AFAIK, you can't get the memory address of an object. Why do you want to get that? What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287425/mutable-vs-immutable-in-scala-collections) and last comment of it, I was trying to test this sentences:"Each time you modify an immutable collection, another collection is produced instead of modifying the original collection in-place."

Comment: Well, you don't need the memory address for that. You can just do `list1 eq list2` check the **Scaladoc**: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html#eq(x$1:AnyRef):Boolean

Comment: Thank you, do you know what is the reason that we can't get the memory address of an object In Scala? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Because the underlying runtime _(the JVM)_ doesn't provide that; which makes sense since the data can be moved into different memory positions automatically.

Comment: Garbage collector in Scala and Java is the same, do you know why Scala behaves different from Java in this case?

Comment: It doesn't, it behaves exactly the same. That is the point I just made. The runtime system doesn't allow you to get memory addresses because it doesn't have any guarantee over those. You can't get them either in **Java**.

Comment: As I know, based on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-object-memory-address#memory-address) we can catch the memory of object in Java, even in runtime, But, as you say, I couldn't do the same in Scala? Right? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Yeah, you can, but again remember that value may be outdated as for the moment you print.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you mean by references. A String is already A reference. If you want to unrefine it ("forget" that the underlying structure is a String) and just have a pure reference you can rely on the fact that the type parameter of a list if covariant and List[String] is a subtype of List[AnyRef].

```
val refs: List[AnyRef] = fruits
```

Not sure why this would be useful tho. Not much you can do with references.

Comment: I mean the memory address of fruit. Can I find it?

Comment: It is impossible to get an address of any primitive variable or object on the JVM. The closes thing is the object hashcode with System.identityHashCode(a). which is related to its address, but there are no guarantees here.

Comment: Ok, I mean Something like this case in Java, That it is the memory reference  in a specific time, Can I have it? Is System.identityHashCode(a) something like that?